# How to use Google Fonts with Sharp on Node.js app deployed on Vercel

Tags: fonts, vercel, sharp, nodejs-server

I deployed my MERN app on Vercel and I use Sharp to convert SVG to Image (png/jpeg) but I have an issue with the fonts. I use Google fonts but I can't install them on Vercel like I did the last time on my own server.

My question is: how can my Node.js app access the fonts so when the conversion with Sharp is done, the text elements will be transformed too (not just generic text with some default system font)?

Thanks!

My app is working fine on other server as I installed all fonts on it. I want to do the same on Vercel.